# Erdös-Renyi-like hypergraphs: threshold for connectedness

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, hypergraphs

Consider an $N$-element set $X$ and a fixed number $k \ll N$.

How many $k$-element subsets $X_i$ (hyperedges) of $X$ do I have to choose (at random) such that (i) $\bigcup_i X_i = X$ and (ii) the intersection graph (with an edge between $X_i$ and $X_j$ when $X_i \cap X_j \neq \emptyset$) is almost surely connected?

I assume this question reduces to the question for the probability that two random $k$-element subsets of $X$ have a common element. Assume that this probability is $p = p(N,k)$. Then if [$p > \frac {(1+\varepsilon )\ln n}{n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G(n,_p)) the intersection graph is almost surely connected, where $n$ is the number I am looking for. But what is $p$?

A more advanced version of this question is: Given a Poisson distribution of hyperedge sizes with mean $k$, how many do I have to choose such that (i) and (ii) above hold?

A follow-up question is this: How does the expected size of the intersection of two hyperedges grow with the number $n$ of hyperedges? (Consider the intersection graph as a weighted graph with edge weights = size of intersection.)

Comment: Can hyperedges repeat?

Comment: @HereToRelax: No, no multi-hyperedges, i.e. the hyperedges are drawn from the $k$-element subsets of $X$ without replacement.

Comment: The argument by comparison to $G(n,p)$ doesn't apply, because edges in the intersection graph aren't independent. You are much more likely to get large cliques.

Comment: An analogy to the $G(n,p)$ connectivity suggests that (i) implies (ii), and that the threshold for (i) happens when the probability of an element being isolated is $\frac1N$. Then we'd want the expected number of hyperedges containing an element to be $\ln N$, and that suggests that the threshold is $\frac{N \ln N}{k}$ edges. Of course there's lots of details missing in this outline.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Thanks for the comments! Can you point me to a resource where I can find this with more details?

Comment: I was just assuming that the same thing happens for the random hypergraph as for the random graph (so copying the argument of Theorem 4.1 [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Book.html) for instance). That being said, it looks like [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1489) does all that and more.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Thanks for the links. Maybe it's worth noting that I'm not asking for the connectedness of the hypergraphs themselves (as considered in Poole's paper) but of the hyperedge (or hyper-[line) graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph), i.e. the graph whose nodes are hyperedges with edges between them when they share a common end node (in the original hypergraph). (Does this make sense?)

Comment: I think those are equivalent! (At least when you also ask for (i) to hold; in general, the hyperline graph could be connected if the original hypergraph has isolated vertices.)